# How to get output parameter and also a table when executing a stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, ado.net

**Scenario**

- I'm working with SQL Server 2017 (not possible to change)
- I'm using Visual Studio 2019 in C# console and .NET Framework 4.5 (possible to change)
- I'm using ADO.NET because several years before we couldn't use Entity Framework, as the system is made to work with a stored procedure that returns at least 100k rows (possible to change)

**Situation**

I have an USP that returns a table that is at least 100k of rows by 20 fields. I need to add an output parameter in order to get also an ID created by the USP itself. So, the situation is that I need return a table and an ID (called `ProcMonitorId`). I don't know if this is even so possible (See workarounds section)

At the SQL level is seems to be so far so good:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [myschema].[mystore]
    @ProcMonitorId BIGINT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
BEGIN TRANSACTION
(...)

    SELECT fields FROM myTable

    SELECT @ProcMonitorId = @internalVariable
```

SQL execution:

[image]

And at repository layer (only relevant lines, someone were surprised for health of example):

```
var command = new SqlCommand("myStoreProcedure", mycon);
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
       
SqlParameter outPutParameter = new SqlParameter();
outPutParameter.ParameterName = "@ProcMonitorId";
outPutParameter.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.BigInt;
outPutParameter.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
command.Parameters.Add(outPutParameter);

// Open connection etc-etc that works
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
string ProcMonitorId = outPutParameter.Value.ToString();

da.Fill(dt);
```

Everything worked fine until the addition of the output at C# level. It returns in the line:

string ProcMonitorId = outPutParameter.Value.ToString();

it returns `NullReferenceException` because `Value` is null (that can't be) and of course, can't convert to String. I would solve this situation by adding a `?` but if that's situation happens for real, I need catch it any way as error. The main idea is that Value can not be null.

As I don't have any ORM map, (and my expertise is not ADO.NET but Entity Framework) I can't understand why is null (No, is not null at SQL layer, always return a value)

**Question**

How can I solve this error or how can I return a `BIGINT` parameter and ALSO a table result?

**Workarounds**

As I first glance I have to solve it quickly, I made a:

```
SELECT 1 as type, @procID as procid, null as data1, null as data2
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 as type, null as procid, data1, data2
```

in order to simulate a "header" and "data" rows on one single table.
But I don't like this solution and is not very elegant and flexible. I've to parse the header every time.

Thanks in advance and please comment anything, tip, help, workaround, I will be glade to update my answer if more information is needed.

Also I can make my Framework to .NET Core or change to Entity Framework. That I can't change is my SQL version

**Update #2**
No changes in SQL - Still working as screenshot
In C# - Hangs out for ever

```
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DbConnection"]);

    connection.Open();
    var command = new SqlCommand("myUSP", connection);
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.CommandTimeout = Convert.ToInt16(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DataBaseTimeOut"]);
    if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        connection.Open();
    }

        SqlParameter r = command.Parameters.Add("@ProcMonitorId", SqlDbType.BigInt);
        r.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (var rdr = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            dt.Load(rdr);
            long id = (long)r.Value;
        }

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);

        da.Fill(dt);
```

Comment: The DataAdapter Fill is not needed because the table has been already loaded in dt.Load (or the inverse of course)

Comment: @Steve you are right, I mix up solutions

Comment: Your procedure has `BEGIN TRANSACTION` but no `COMMIT`. Ideally you need to use `while (rdr.NextResult) { }` to ensure all the SQL is executed, but in this case try putting the `SELECT @ProcMonitorId` first

Comment: @Charlieface the commit is included in the (...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter value won't be available until after you consume the resultset, eg

```
var cmd0 = new SqlCommand("create or alter procedure pFoo @id int output as begin  select * from sys.objects; set @id = 12; end", con);
cmd0.ExecuteNonQuery();

var cmd = new SqlCommand("pFoo", con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

var p1 = cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int);
p1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;


var dt = new DataTable();
using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{                    
    dt.Load(rdr);
    var id = (int)p1.Value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! let met try this. Sorry for my ignorance: I should do some change to my original USP? I should set @id as OUTPUT ?

Comment: Yes.  You should use an OUTPUT parameter.

Comment: Now it works for SQL again (as same in the screenshot) but TimeOuts in C#

Comment: Timeout is a client setting.  SqlCommand.CommandTimeout. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0

Comment: yes, yes, I used 2 hours, but is abbout hang out. But I think is other problem, not the ADO

Comment: Make sure it's not blocked by an open transaction, eg in an SSMS query window.  `select * from sys.dm_tran_locks`, `sp_who`, etc.

Comment: I back to the state that I could still running the USP to check everything. OK. So then I do your changes as suggested. I update my question with that code. Still hangs out. It's a big question to me why :S No message or exception. Just hangs out until the timeout setted up

Comment: Troubleshoot on the server by querying the DMVs like `select * 
from sys.dm_exec_requests `

Answer (score 0):

You should use a Parameter with the Direction property set to [ReturnValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.parameterdirection?view=netframework-4.8), and, inside the sp, declare an internal variable and set it to the value you want.
Then call the RETURN statement before leaving the StoredProcedure.

As an example, see this SP:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [GetTimeZoneGMT]
    @TimeZone NVARCHAR(128)
AS
BEGIN
 DECLARE @timeZoneNumber as INT = -20;
 IF @TimeZone ='Pacific/Midway'
    SET @timeZoneNumber = -11
 ELSE IF @TimeZone ='Pacific/Niue'
    SET @timeZoneNumber = -11
 ELSE IF @TimeZone ='Pacific/Pago_Pago'
    SET @timeZoneNumber = -11

 SELECT 1 -- or whatever you need to have as result set

 RETURN @timeZoneNumber;
END
```

The stored procedure ends with a (bogus) SELECT statement but also has a RETURN statement with the parameter set inside the SP logic.

Now from the C# side you could call it in this way (LinqPad example)

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LOCAL);Initial Catalog=LinqPADTest;Integrated Security=True;"))
{ 
    connection.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetTimeZoneGMT", connection);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@TimeZone", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "Asia/Kuala_Lumpur";

    SqlParameter r = cmd.Parameters.Add("@p2", SqlDbType.BigInt);
    r.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
    
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
    
    r.Value.Dump();  // Prints -20
    dt.Dump();       // Prints a row with a single column with 1 as value     
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot! Uhm, let me try! For sure i didn't use the RETURN.

Comment: I tried, but now it waits forever. In SQL doesn't return the parameter. Only the first select. I just update my question

Comment: RETURN values aren't for sending data to clients.  They are for reporting stored procedure success or failure to other TSQL code.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft not want to argue but then why we have a SqlParameter with direction = ReturnValue. It seems just a rule not written and not enforced anywhere to me. I use it when I need it and without side-effects as far as I know

Comment: Yes, it's just a best-practice.